# Python similar method in multiple classes

Tags: python, django, class, django-rest-framework, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to re-factor my Django app. Here is the repeated code i found annoying :

```
class EducationInfoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = pf.education_info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EducationInfoSerializer
    permission_classes = (VisionUserPermissions, )

    def get_queryset(self):

        model = pf.education_info

        identity = self.request.query_params.get('username',None)
        queryset = model.objects.all()
        user = User.objects.none()
        if identity is not None:
            user = User.objects.get(username=identity)
            student = get_object_or_404(dbd.user_type, username=user)        
            queryset = model.objects.filter(username=student)
        if not permission_check(self.request,user):
            return User.objects.none()
        return queryset


class FamilyInfoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = pf.family_info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilyInfoSerializer
    permission_classes = (VisionUserPermissions, )

    def get_queryset(self):

        model = pf.family_info

        identity = self.request.query_params.get('username',None)
        queryset = model.objects.all()
        user = User.objects.none()
        if identity is not None:
            user = User.objects.get(username=identity)
            student = get_object_or_404(dbd.user_type, username=user)        
            queryset = model.objects.filter(username=student)
        if not permission_check(self.request,user):
            return User.objects.none()
        return queryset
```

So my "get_queryset" functions are identical other than one variable, and i have multiple classes like these two. How should I implement this without repeating myself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read this [article](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/) about inheritance in python

Comment: Create an InfoViewSet class that has all of the common methods.  Then create the Family and Education classes and have them inherit from InfoViewSet and only implement methods in those that differ.

Comment: Thanks for the article and this entire idea guys! I didn't realize that class inheritance could be so flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a mixing class

```
class QuerysetMixin(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):

        model = getattr(pf, self.field_name)

        identity = self.request.query_params.get('username',None)
        queryset = model.objects.all()
        user = User.objects.none()
        if identity is not None:
            user = User.objects.get(username=identity)
            student = get_object_or_404(dbd.user_type, username=user)        
            queryset = model.objects.filter(username=student)
        if not permission_check(self.request,user):
            return User.objects.none()
        return queryset
```

and inherit it

```
class FamilyInfoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, QuerysetMixin):

    queryset = pf.family_info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilyInfoSerializer
    permission_classes = (VisionUserPermissions, )
    field_name = 'family_info'
```

Comment: You might have meant "mixin" rather than "mixing."

Comment: Setting the "field_name" is exactly the clever way i did not come up with!! Thanks so much. BTW, shouldn't "QuerysetMixing" be the only parameter? I don't see the point for "FamilyInfoViewSet" to have two parameters.